# How can I trap all mouse events on a control?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to capture all mouse events on a .NET's WebBrowser, process them and prevent the WebBrowser from getting them. Is there any way to achieve this? I wonder if there is any way I can handle mouse events if the control is disabled.

Comment: If you are using WPF, you could lay a transparent canvas over the top of the WebBrowser control and simply catch all events with the Canvas...Winforms is a different story, though.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268619/catching-a-contained-controls-mouse-events-in-a-usercontrol

Comment: this reads a bit weird suely you would ignore them? Why go through the trouble if trapping events if you have no real desire of doing anything with them? Just ignore them???

Comment: I'll process them myself. I need to customize WebBrowser's default functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to override WndProc() to intercept the mouse messages.  Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyBrowser : WebBrowser {
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg >= 0x200 && m.Msg <= 0x20a) {
            // Handle mouse messages
            //...
        }
        else base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: a (non exhaustive) list of windows messages can be found here http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/SendMessageList.htm

Answer (score 3):

There IS a solution to this. You need to capture the mouse events that are associated with the Document object that is associated with the webBrowser control.

After the DocumentCompleted event occurs, and inside you DocumentCompleted event handler, do the following:

```
myWebBrowser.Document.MouseDown += new HtmlElementEventHandler(myMouseDown);
```

and have the related handler:

```
void myMouseDown(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)

{
    your code to handle the mouse event... such as ...

            if (e.MouseButtonsPressed == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
            }
}
```