# Enable scrolling again

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

My goal is to disable controls (textboxe,radiobutton,...) and all their children (for example the tabs of a tabitem) when the user enters the UI in read only mode.

The only exceptions are the scrollbars which should be enabled even if it's readonly.

This is done quit elegently by the following code found on SO. Doing it this way lets the IsEnabled property inherit to all it children while allowing an the scrollbar to be enabled.

```
public class AlwaysEnabledTabControlTabItem : TabItem
{
    static AlwaysEnabledTabControlTabItem()
    {
            IsEnabledProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                                               typeof(AlwaysEnabledTabControlTabItem),
                                               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                                   null,
                                                   (o,
                                                    value) => true));
    }
}
```

The problem is wth the scrollwheel of the mouse (and the page up/down keys) which does not work anymore.
When you are on the tab and want to scroll nothing happens. As a side node, the mouse wheel works if you are on the narrow scrollbar itself.

How would you enable the scrollwheel as well?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure but I guess it does not work because there are no events handled for inactive controls -> using the mouse wheel on the disabled tab page does nothing. It may work if you enable the single tab page, but not its controls.

Otherwise you could try to use WndProc to capture mouse input, as done here:

[How can I trap all mouse events on a control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471839/how-can-i-trap-all-mouse-events-on-a-control)

(more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx )

and then use this to change the scroll position (you might need to enable the control while using auto scroll):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition.aspx

There should be something similar to intercept keyboard input, but unfortunately I dont have any information on that.